# Create unstripped executable for android with .bp

Tags: android, debugging, gdb, android-soong

I want to build aosp native test and debug it on emulator. Is it possible to build executable with debugging symbols?
I have tried to add *-g* and *-ggdb* to Android .bp:

```
    cflags: [
        "-Werror",
        "-Wall",
        "-g",
    ],
```

but it didn't help, I still getting stripped executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the module declaration, add:

```
            strip: {
                keep_symbols: true,
            },
```

Reference: [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/379e05fd5df54f23a75a50efe457ecadf44a68b1/libc/Android.bp#1659).

Answer (score 2):

You can find the unstripped binaries in `$ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT/symbols`.